# How to make dispatch call synchronous in useeffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, core-ui

i am trying to paginate the data from my rest server using CoreUI Table Component.
i have problem getting the updated data from redux store after dispatch request in useEffect, i am using redux thunk, i know that dispatch is async, but is there a way to wait for the dispatch to be completed? i tired making the dispatch a Promise but it did not work.

I successfully get the updated result from action and reducer but in ProductsTable its the previous one, i checked redux devtools extension and i can see the state being changed.

i never get the latest value from store.

Also the dispatch is being called so many times i can see in the console window, it nots an infinite loop, it stops after sometime.

```
const ProductsTable = (props) => {


    const store = useSelector((state) => state.store);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [pages, setPages] = useState(1);
    const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);
    const [fetchTrigger, setFetchTrigger] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);


        const payload = {
            params: {
                page,
            },
        };

        if (page !== 0)
            dispatch(getAllProducts(payload));

        console.log("runs:" + page)
        console.log(store.objects)

        if(!(Object.keys(store.objects).length === 0)){
            setItems(store.objects.results)
            setPages(store.objects.total.totalPages)
            setLoading(false)
        } else{
            console.log("error")
            setFetchTrigger(fetchTrigger + 1);
        }

    }, [page, fetchTrigger]);


    return (
        <CCard className="p-5">
            <CDataTable
                items={items}
                fields={["title", "slug", {
                    key: 'show_details',
                    label: '',
                    _style: { width: '1%' },
                    sorter: false,
                    filter: false
                }]}
                loading={loading}
                hover
                cleaner
                sorter
                itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
                onPaginationChange={setItemsPerPage}
              
            <CPagination
                pages={pages}
                activePage={page}
                onActivePageChange={setPage}
                className={pages < 2 ? "d-none" : ""}
            />



        </CCard>




    )
}


export default ProductsTable
```

Comment: What makes you think `dispatch` is asynchronous? Out-of-the-box all redux actions and reducers are synchronous. Also, `useEffect` callbacks are also synchronous. Sounds like you actually want all the logic from your `useEffect` callback to *actually* run in an asynchronous action (via a Thunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `ProductsTable` always has the previous state data is because the effect you use to update the `ProductsTable` is missing the `store` as dependency or more specifically `store.objects.results`; when the `page` and the `fetchTrigger` change the effect becomes stale because it isn't aware that when those dependencies change the effect should change.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // store.objects is a dependency that is not tracked
    if (!(Object.keys(store.objects).length === 0)) {
      // store.objects.results is a dependency that is not tracked
      setItems(store.objects.results);
      // store.objects.total.totalPages is a dependency that is not tracked
      setPages(store.objects.total.totalPages);
      setLoading(false);
    }  
    // add these dependencies to the effect so that everything works as expected
    // avoid stale closures 
  }, [page, fetchTrigger, store.objects, store.objects.results, store.objects.total.totalPages]);
```

The dispatch is being called many times because you have a recursive case where `fetchTrigger` is a dependency of the effect but you also update it from within the effect. By removing that dependency you'll see much less calls to this effect, namely only when the page changes. I don't know what you need that value for because I dont see it used in the code you've shared, but if you do need it I recommend using the `callback` version of setState so that you can reference the value of `fetchTrigger` that you need without needing to add it as a dependency.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // code
    if (!(Object.keys(store.objects).length === 0)) {
      // code stuffs
    } else {
      // use the callback version of setState to get the previous/current value of fetchTrigger
      // so you can remove the dependency on the fetchTrigger
      setFetchTrigger(fetchTrigger => fetchTrigger + 1);
    }
    // remove fetchTrigger as a dependency
  }, [page, store.objects, store.objects.results, store.objects.totalPages]);
```

With those issues explained, you'd be better off not adding new state for your `items`, `pages`, or `loading` and instead deriving that from your redux store, because it looks like thats all it is.

```
const items = useSelector((state) => state.store.objects?.results);
const pages = useSelector((state) => state.store.objects?.total?.totalPages);
const loading = useSelector((state) => !Object.keys(state.store.objects).length === 0);
```

and removing the effect entirely in favor of a function to add to the `onActivePageChange` event.

```
  const onActivePageChange = page => {
    setPage(page); 
    setFetchTrigger(fetchTrigger => fetchTrigger + 1);
    dispatch(getAllProducts({
      params: {
        page,
      },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <CPagination
      // other fields
      onActivePageChange={onActivePageChange}
    />
  );
```

But for initial results you will still need some way to fetch, you can do this with an effect that only runs once when the component is mounted. This should do that because dispatch should not be changing.

```
  // on mount lets get the initial results
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      getAllProducts({
        params: {
          page: 1,
        },
      })
    );
  },[dispatch]);
```

Together that would look like this with the recommended changes:

```
const ProductsTable = props => {
  const items = useSelector(state => state.store.objects?.results);
  const pages = useSelector(state => state.store.objects?.total?.totalPages);
  const loading = useSelector(state => !Object.keys(state.store.objects).length === 0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [fetchTrigger, setFetchTrigger] = useState(0);

  // on mount lets get the initial results
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      getAllProducts({
        params: {
          page: 1,
        },
      })
    );
  },[dispatch]);

  const onActivePageChange = page => {
    setPage(page);
    setFetchTrigger(fetchTrigger => fetchTrigger + 1);
    dispatch(
      getAllProducts({
        params: {
          page,
        },
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <CCard className="p-5">
      <CDataTable
        items={items}
        fields={[
          'title',
          'slug',
          {
            key: 'show_details',
            label: '',
            _style: { width: '1%' },
            sorter: false,
            filter: false,
          },
        ]}
        loading={loading}
        hover
        cleaner
        sorter
        itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
        onPaginationChange={setItemsPerPage}
      />

      <CPagination
        pages={pages}
        activePage={page}
        onActivePageChange={onActivePageChange}
        className={pages < 2 ? 'd-none' : ''}
      />
    </CCard>
  );
};

export default ProductsTable;
```

Comment: Thanks your code works, and it does not make multiple dispatches like useEffect, only problem is on first page load the table is empty, and CPagination is infinite, but when i click on any page, it shows the data and works fine, is there any way to fix this and show data on first load, i think its because on first load the totalPages from store is empty and it comes to store first time when getAllProducts dispatches and return totalPages, because my rest api return totalPages constant with all the products, so i think its important to first make a request to api with page=1. Thank you support.

Comment: For the initial items you will need a useEffect, but it will be a very simple effect because its only for the 'on mount' case of the component I've added that to the answer. And what do you mean by 'CPagination is infinite' ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need any synchronous to achieve the results you want, you have to switch up your code so it doesn't use the state of react since you are already using some kind of global store ( i assume redux ); what you need to do is grab all the items straight from the store don't do an extra logic on the component (read for the separation of concerns); Also I would suggest to do the pagination on the server side not just paginate data on the front end. (getAllProducts() method to switch on fetching just a page of results and not all the products); Your code have alot of dispatches because you are using page and fetchTrigger as dependencies of useEffect hook that means every time the page or fetchTrigger value changes the code inside useEffect will run again resulting in another dispatch;

Here is a slightly modified part of your code, you need to add some extra stuff on your action and a loading param in your global state

```
const ProductsTable = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
 // PUT THE LOADING IN THE GLOBAL STATE OR HANDLE IT VIA A CALLBACK OR ADD A GLOBAL MECHANISM TO HANLE LOADINGS INSIDE THE APP
const loading = useSelector(() => state.store.loading)
const items = useSelector((state) => state.store.objects?.results); // ADD DEFAULT EMPTY VALUES FOR objects smthg like : { objects: { results: [], total: { totalPages: 0 } }}
const pages = useSelector((state) => state.store.objects?.total?.totalPages);

const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);

const [fetchTrigger, setFetchTrigger] = useState(0); // I DONT UNDERSTAND THIS ONE

const fetchData = () => dispatch(getAllProducts({ params: { page }}));

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
    <CCard className="p-5">
        <CDataTable
            items={items}
            fields={["title", "slug", {
                key: 'show_details',
                label: '',
                _style: { width: '1%' },
                sorter: false,
                filter: false
            }]}
            loading={loading}
            hover
            cleaner
            sorter
            itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
            onPaginationChange={setItemsPerPage}
        <CPagination
            pages={pages}
            activePage={page}
            onActivePageChange={setPage}
            className={pages < 2 ? "d-none" : ""}
        />
    </CCard>
)

}

export default ProductsTable
```